# Scalar potential and Flux

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, line-integrals

$\vec{v}$ is a conservative vector field such that 
$$
\vec{v} = f(r)(x,y), \text{ where } r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
$f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ and is continuously differentiable

1. Work out the scalar potential of $\vec{v}$ involving $f$
2. Find the anti clockwise flux $$\oint_{C_{R}} \vec{v} \cdot n ds$$ in terms of $f$ and find all $f$ such that the flux is independent of $R$. $C_R$ is the circle centered at (0,0) with radius $R$

I know how to work this out without $f$ complicating things, I just don't know how to apply the same methods with $f$, e.g when finding the scalar potentials and setting the scalar potential equal to the integral of each component of $\vec{v}$ how would you integrate the expression involving $f$.

Sorry if I have not explained things too well, any help is appreciated!

Comment: By 'work out the scalar potential' you mean "find $\phi(x,y)$ such that $\vec{v}=\nabla \phi$"? For that it may be useful to consider what the streamlines of $\vec{v}$ are, and what the equipotential lines should look line to match that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_R}\vec v \cdot \hat n\,ds&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left.\left(f(r)\left(\hat xx+\hat yy\right)\frac{\hat xx+\hat yy}{r}\,r\right)\right|_{r=R}\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\pi R^2f(R)
\end{align}$$

is independent of $R$ if and only if $\displaystyle f(r)=\frac{A}{r^2}$ for some constant $A$.

---

To find the scalar potential, $\Phi$, for $\vec v$, we solve the equation $\nabla \Phi =\vec v$.  In polar coordinates, $(r,\theta)$, this becomes

$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r}=rf(r)\implies \Phi(r)=\int^r r'f(r')\,dr'$$

Comment: I don't understand how you converted it to polar coordinates and why are you integrating with respect to r'

Comment: @BradleyHill The "Del" operator in polar coordinates is $$\nabla =\hat r\frac{\partial }{\partial r}+\hat \theta \frac1r \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}$$The integration variable $r'$ is only a "dummy" variable.